# setCustomValidity is only applied on the 2nd click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation

I have a Vue app where I have the following piece of logic:

```
if (
     this.registration.user.password !==
     this.registration.user.password_confirmation
   ) {
        console.log('check')
        document
          .getElementById('password_confirmation')
          .setCustomValidity('Passwords do not match')
      }
```

This logic sits inside a `registerUser` method that appears in `<form ... @submit="registerUser">`. I noticed that when I click on the submit button when the 2 passwords are not equal, nothing at all happens the first time, but in the logs I can still see 'check' printed. The 2nd time I click the submit button, I get the validation error.

Does anyone know what's wrong here? Why does this note happen the 2nd time?

EDIT:

I think I've worked it out. The problem was that I was setting validation inside my registerUser method which is triggered *after* a click occurs, so it's already too late to prevent it via form patterns. I fixed it by calling the password checker specifically inside the `@onchange` call, like this:

```
<input
        ref="password_confirmation"
        v-model="registration.user.password_confirmation"
        type="password"
        placeholder="Repeat password..."
        required
        oninput="setCustomValidity('')"
        @change="checkConfirmation"
      />
```

and my `checkConfirmation` method is just this:

```
checkConfirmation() {
      const form = this.registration.user
      if (form.password === form.password_confirmation) {
        this.$refs.password_confirmation.setCustomValidity('')
      } else {
        this.$refs.password_confirmation.setCustomValidity(
          'Passwords do not match'
        )
      }
    }
```

A few important notes:

- You need the `oninput="setCustomValidity('')"` otherwise if you enter an incorrect input and then fix it, the error will not go away
- The above approach is still not bulletproof -- if a user does not input a valid (if it's prefilled) then the validation will pass. This applies to both pattern checks and on-change validations.

Comment: `oninput` does not exist, the correct one is `@input`. You should probably throw the `@change` + `@input` and replace them with a watch with `immediate: true` (https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) to watch `registration.user.password_confirmation`. Also, you may probably replace `v-model` by a `:value` + `@input` since it's just sugar syntax in this case (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components). That way, you can ditch the `ref` too.

Comment: Alright, you can basically ignore what I wrote above and check my updated answer, it will give you a super simple way of checking the validity (equality) of the 2 fields. It's efficient (because computed properties), with not a lot of code and it should totally work if you have prefilled values. If you aim for more complex and flexible validations, I can still heavily recommend [vee-validate](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/guide/rules.html#confirmed).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: alright, a far more easier way of writing things would be the following (if the end goal is to check the equality of 2 fields):

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="checkPasswordFields">
      <input v-model="password" placeholder="input password" />
      <input v-model="passwordConfirmation" placeholder="confirm password" />
      <button>submit</button>
    </form>

    <p>do password match ? >> {{ doPasswordMatch }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      password: '',
      passwordConfirmation: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkPasswordFields() {
      console.log(`Password do${this.doPasswordMatch ? '' : ' not'} match !`)
    },
  },
  computed: {
    doPasswordMatch() {
      return this.password === this.passwordConfirmation
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

---

This is probably coming from the fact that your DOM did not re-render before passing into your `setCustomValidity` method. Depending when you do have your condition, Vue may have not yet updated it's state.

First off, you should switch your `document.getElementById` to `$refs` as explained here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements

So, it may look something like

```html
<base-input ref="passwordConfirmation"></base-input>
```

and then, you do select your element with

```js
this.$refs.passwordConfirmation
```

This alone, may maybe fix the issue.

---

If it's not enough, you may also squeeze a

```js
await this.$nextTick()
```

before your condition. That way, you will wait for Vue to update it's state before proceeding.

Of course, there may be a more usual way of doing this without relying on the `nextTick` *hack*, but it all comes down to your code logic here and we will need more of it.

A good clean alternative is to use the package `vee-validate`, which will help you make more concise and better structured front-end validations: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/guide/rules.html#confirmed

---

To answer the last part of your question: it does happen the 2nd time because Vue has it's state updated on the 2nd run.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Unfortunately using refs and nextTick didn't help and I'm still getting the validation error on the 2nd click only

Comment: We will need some [repro] here, or more code at least to move forward. Some vue devtools debugging results can be useful too !

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back, but I think I worked it out (kind of), although there are still a few outstanding concerns about that. Please see my updated question description

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, but it still doesn't fix the original problem. As I explained in my question, the problem is that the validation occurs on the 2nd click only and the way to fix it is to use `@change` inside the form field and link it to the function that sets custom validity. To deal with pre-filled values, I use vuelidate which is similar to vee-validate.

Comment: Change is called on the `blur` event, while `input` is done on each keystroke. Did you tried my solution? Not sure where it falls down.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but your answer does not use HTML pattern validation with custom validity which was my main objective here

Comment: HTML pattern validation, like this one? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp You can totally chain both in `computed` tbh.

Comment: Yes and I already solved it. There is no need for `computed` or `watch` when using `@change`

Comment: Thanks for looking into this problem anyway, you gave me some useful tips for how to get to the solution

Comment: Glad I helped somehow. And yeah, at the end, you can do this in several ways !